# Best Water-Heater Location

Tags: water-heater

Is it OK to install a gas water heater next to a gas dryer and if not what are the cautions? Both will be vented. Thanks

Comment: what are the clearance requirements for the two appliances?

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with them being located next to one another. They both need to be serviceable and they both need adequate combustion air.  And proper venting for both.